# FM radio interference on PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, interference, emi-filtering

I have designed a few PCBs for one of my projects. The PCB is picking up FM radio signals. I can see this as spikes in the spectrum where each radio station is broadcasting.

I tried covering the PCB with a grounded aluminum foil (many layers) to act as a Faraday cage. Although it reduced the signal's amplitude a little, the suppression is minimal.

The PCBs have highly sensitive sections where this amount of noise cannot be tolerated. The PCB has its ground connected to the copper pour.

Can anyone suggest ideas on how to get rid of this noise?

I am attaching an image of the noise spectrum.

[image: Spectrum]

A schematic of the PCB is attached below.[image]

We are seeing RF interference on every conductive material, not necessarily on the PCB. Hence, any general techniques typically used in such situations would be useful. I have included a ruler to enable scale measurements.

Comment: How is it picking up these signals? Does your pcb have RF circuitry on it? It could be your circuitry promotes the reception, so no amount of shielding is going to help you. Without knowing the details of your circuit we can’t conjure up any magic solutions.

Comment: 'covering the PCB with foil' is unlikely to create an effective Faraday cage, the devil is in the detail. Your use of the qualifier 'grounded' foil supports that, grounding the foil does nothing to stopping radio reception via a Faraday cage. It needs to surround the circuit entirely, topologically equivalent to a conductive sphere around the circuit. Now obviously DC has to go in, and signals need to enter and exit. You manage this through filtered penetrations of that sphere. The design of the that filtering is what sets a successful Faraday screened circuit apart from an unsuccesful one.

Comment: @Kartman, The PCB does not have any RF circuitry. One of the PCBs, which is a power distribution board, also is showing noise at the ground terminals. Just by probing the ground terminal with a scope, I can observe the noise. Even when using a BNC cable with one end connected to the scope and the other end open, I can see similar spectra (with a reduced amplitude). Any general ideas typically done in such scenarious would be helpful.

Comment: @Neil_UK, For testing purposes, no DC connections were going in or out (eventually they have to). The PCB was covered fully with the foil. The only connection going out of the foil was a BNC cable to the scope. The ground of the BNC cable was connected to the aluminum foil.

Comment: How close are you to the antennas? I once worked at a company that was really close to an AM antenna (200 yards). You could easily see it on a scope with just a few inches of wire. Fortunately they didn't design sensitive electronics.

Comment: Is the RF getting into your electronics and causing problems?  You could connect you scope to anything metallic and get the same results - we’re talking microvolts of RF.  I could understand a problem if you had circuitry that was high impedance, low level analog and the RF was causing saturation, then I’d suggest some ferrite beads and 100pF capacitors.

Comment: @Mattman944 We do not know the exact location of the antennas. They won't be far away as this is a very populated area.

Comment: What is the length of the trace you are measuring those signal on?
Could you please provide a schematic or at least a picture of your PCB?
It's not rare for a long trace, to pickup many signals.
A trace will start picking up signal when it's length is superior to Lambda/30 of the frequency for example.

Comment: @Kartman We design photodiodes. These devices need high gain amplification stages where the RF is indeed causing saturation. The analog signals we are using have frequencies of few MHz. Hence, using ferrite beads and bypass capacitors will affect our system. So, we need some way to prevent the RF from getting into the system.

Comment: As we don't see the top of the board ... have you used decoupling capacitors correctly placed?

Comment: @Antonio51 Yes, there are decoupling capacitors. But, the problem we are facing is not specific to the particular PCB. Any metal strip is picking up RF interference. What I was interested in is general techniques that are used to avoid RF interference being injected into the system.

Comment: Who closed this question? Seriously? Author added circuit board WITH a ruler to have a sense of scale of what is going on.
Seriously what is wrong with the person closing question like this???
This board could have been a great example of what can be put in place to better EMC protection...

Comment: Ok. What i see is that the board(?) is "big"... as wires are long, it is always possible that interferences occurs easy. Schematic? Not only pcb.

Comment: However, something is strange in your pcb about "end wiring" (?).

Comment: Ferrite beads should leave your MHz signals intact and will attenuate 10’s of MHz. Maybe 100pF is too large, go for something smaller. Some filtering should go some way to attenuating the FM signals. Use a simulator to model the effect. Once you understand where the interference is getting in, then you can target that with filtering etc. even just putting a 100pF cap from 0V to a suspect node should give some indication if you’re targetting the correct area. Sure it will limit the bandwidth of your signal of interest, but if it kills off the interference, then  you’re in the right area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thank you for the PCB.

There is many things to take into account when designing a board which should be resilient to EMF radiation. One may be tempted to wrap the thing into aluminium foil, or in a big metallic box. This is not the right direction to start.

**Big metalic shielding boxes are hard to design and very expensive**  i.e. Farday cages

When you want to shield your thing in a box you have to :

1. Make sure there isn't any slot in the resulting assembly.
   Because EM radiation can enter them pretty easily.
2. So if you want an opening you will have to put some contacts fingers, which have to make electrical contacts between pieces to cut the slot. For that you have to put special contacts, with special materials so oxidation don't electrically open those contacts.
3. And finally, you will want wire in and out, so take care in shielding.
4. Basically this list goes on forever, it's exhausting and expansive.

**So what do I do? Start by bullet proofing your board**
In this regard, your design as a few mistakes :

5. Many GND vias everywhere: to ensure GND coherence. Meaning your GND should be at the same potential everywhere. What distance appart? (Lambda/30) your problem is at 100MHz so let's take 110Mhz (wavelength shorter) this means your problematic wavelength is 270cm so your via stitching should be no further than 9cm appart. This is big way to big so we ditch the thumb rule, and something around 0.5cm appart should be great. The goals is to have no copper tongue left, image 1. And this shielding will be important for the following point, so you want to fence yours signals with vias close alongside them.
6. You have very long traces on your PCB, which act as antennas, I mean, they literally collect EMF radiation. A wire become an antenna from an EMC perspective when it become bigger than.... You guessed Lambda/30, so your are clearly in this range. "But what do I do have to take this signal from point A to point B?" You could use a 4 layer PCB, yes it's more expansive, but burying your signal between two GNDs will shield it from the outside. And as you added GNDs vias everywhere, the signal will not have any slot left on the PCB sides to couple to your trace.
7. Shunt the parasitic signal to the GND
   Using a low pass filter, with Ksim (KEMET capacitor simulator) I was able to find a capacitor value able to shunt the 100MHz region while, not harming the signal of interest in the MHz region (image 2). The curve is a S21 in shunt configuration, so you inject frequencies at side 1, and see what is left at side 2, with the capacitor in the middle. This capacitor could be placed at either side of the trace, or simply at the measuring side. The simulated capacitor is a 2nF capacitor, so it shouldn't mess with the SOI.

[image: Grounding copper tongues]
[image: Capacitor selection]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I'll try out the suggested techniques.